# Gatsby page-data.json is not loaded from cache by service worker generated with gatsby-plugin-offline

Tags: gatsby, workbox

I have a GatsbyJS-v5 website and I'm trying to make it working in offline mode. I'm using `gatsby-plugin-offline` for this aim.
My service worker installed, activated and is running when I'm online:

[image: Service worker activated and is running]

Cache storage is not empty, so it proves that `gatsby-plugin-offline` actually works:

[image: Cache storage when online]

Options for the plugin in my `gatsby-config.js` are really simple:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
      options: {
        precachePages: [`/`, `/articles`, `/articles/*`],
        workboxConfig: {
          importWorkboxFrom: `cdn`,
        },
      },
    },
```

But when I'm switching my page into the Offline mode in DevTools I'm getting the same error all the time:

[image: Error: Failed to fetch]

Here is the reason of the error (code from sw.js):

[image: Failed to fetch]

Evidently, the service worker can't get the `page-data.json` from cache. But why? I don't have custom settings in my `gatsby-config.js`, so the page-data.js is loaded with the default [Stale-while-revalidate](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/caching-strategies-overview/#stale-while-revalidate) strategy and `page-data.json` must be cached and extracted from cache first. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to change different default plugin settings but with no result. The expected behavior is working website in offline mode, but the result is the error in console and the discouraging page view in browser:

[image: :(]